# Cassandra backup directory i occuping 2GB

Tags: linux

I am using Cassandra, I have observed in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/batchlog directory , backups directory is occupying 2GB and I have observed incremental_backups in cassandra.yaml is enabled, what if i remove backups directory in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/batchlog ?

Please help me !!!

Comment: Need more clarification for your question

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does not automatically clear incremental backup files. DataStax recommends setting up a process to clear incremental backup hard-links each time a new snapshot is created.

what if i remove backups directory in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/batchlog

backups directory is re-created after restart cassandra. if you don't keep incremental_backups.
edit the cassandra.yaml configuration file on each node in the cluster and change the value of
incremental_backups to false

Comment: You obviously got your answer from http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra_win/2.2/cassandra/operations/opsBackupIncremental.html, but you don't mention that in your answer.  Please give credit where it is due.